# How do you pass in another object of the same type as a method parameter in python?

Tags: python, object, methods, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am creating a class in python to represent a three-dimensional point (I know there are libraries to do this, it's more of an exercise in classes). One type of method I wish to have is one which can add the coordinates of one point to another. I've tried doing this by passing the other point as a parameter in the method:

```
class Point:
    crd = [0,0,0]

    def add_vector(self, coord = [], *args) :
        self.crd[0] += coord[0]
        self.crd[1] += coord[1]
        self.crd[2] += coord[2]

    def subtract_point_from_point(self, other) :
        self.crd[0] = self.crd[0] - other.crd[0]
        self.crd[1] = self.crd[1] - other.crd[1]
        self.crd[2] = self.crd[2] - other.crd[2]
```

I tested the class with the following code and it didn't behave as I would expect:

```
a = Point()
b = [2, 2, 4]
a.add_vector(b)

print('Before making c:')
print('a.crd: ' + str(a.crd[0]))
print('a.crd: ' + str(a.crd[1]))
print('a.crd: ' + str(a.crd[2]))

c = Point()
d = [7, 7, 9]
c.add_vector(d)

print('After adding d to c:')
print('a.crd: ' + str(a.crd[0]))
print('a.crd: ' + str(a.crd[1]))
print('a.crd: ' + str(a.crd[2]))

a.subtract_point_from_point(c)

print('After making c: ')
print('a.crd: ' + str(a.crd[0]))
print('a.crd: ' + str(a.crd[1]))
print('a.crd: ' + str(a.crd[2]))
```

Produces:

```
Before making c:
a.crd: 2
a.crd: 2
a.crd: 4
After adding d to c:
a.crd: 9
a.crd: 9
a.crd: 13
After making c:
a.crd: 0
a.crd: 0
a.crd: 0
```

What causes `a` to change when adding `d` to `c`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're defining `crd` as a static property on `Point`. This means that all instances of `Point` share the same list `crd`. To fix this, create a constructor (`__init__()`) and define `self.crd` there. Like this:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self):
        self.crd = [0, 0, 0]

    def add_vector(self, coord=[], *args):
        self.crd[0] += coord[0]
        self.crd[1] += coord[1]
        self.crd[2] += coord[2]

    def subtract_point_from_point(self, other):
        self.crd[0] = self.crd[0] - other.crd[0]
        self.crd[1] = self.crd[1] - other.crd[1]
        self.crd[2] = self.crd[2] - other.crd[2]
```